# Flexbox with Bootstrap 5 and Aspect Ratio

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-5

The following code creates a two column layout, using bootstrap and flexbox, where left column shows video description and the right column shows the embedded video.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-12 pe-md-2 order-md-first order-last">
    placeholder
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-12 ps-md-2 ratio ratio-16x9">
        <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WUgvvPRH7Oc?controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the correct aspect ratio breaks the bounds set by the flexbox. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .ratio class sets the width to 100% so it interferes with the .col% family of clases.
You could nest the  with the ratio class under the .col:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5 order-md-first order-last">
      placeholder
    </div>
    <div class="col-7" <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
      <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WUgvvPRH7Oc?controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the guidance in the [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/columns/)...

"When building grid layouts, all **content goes in columns**. The hierarchy of Bootstrap’s grid goes from container to row to column to your content. On rare occasions, you may combine content and column, but be aware there can be unintended consequences."

Therefore you need a the aspect ratio *inside* the column...

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-12 pe-md-2 order-md-first order-last">
    placeholder
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7 col-12 ps-md-2">
        <div class="ratio ratio-16x9">
           <iframe width="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/WUgvvPRH7Oc?controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```